# program "make" not found in path while building a project

Tags: path, makefile

When i was trying to build any project in eclipse c/c++, i am getting an error as program "make" not found.I am using mingw gcc compiler. i had tried many ways to solve the issue but nothing worked for me . All the below ways has been tried and i couldn't resolve it.

1.I tried setting the environment variable
2.Tried renaming the mingw32-make to make.exe
3.in window-->preferences-->c/c++-->Build-->environment-->setting new variable for mingw

Can anyone suggest me a solution to rectify this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I tried different things but atlast i got it rectified by doing the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5BpX.png)

1.Before running the code i had changed the toolchain editor from project---> properties-->c/c++ build --->Toolchain editor---> change the current tool chain editor to MinGW GCC(Since i was using mingw compiler).